# conda install mingw for 64bit CentOS 7

Tags: installation, mingw, anaconda, conda

I just installed Anaconda 2 on a linux machine with 64 bit CentOS 7. I tried:

```
conda install mingw libpython
```

but it says:

> conda install mingw libpython
>
> Fetching package metadata .........
>
> PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: Conda could not find '

Comment: Is that really what it says? It doesn't show the package that it cannot find?

Comment: No, it doesn't show the package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the error message is extremely unhelpful, the error is that `libpython` is only available for Windows: https://anaconda.org/search?q=libpython